# A sensible way of linking two objects

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have two vectors of objects:

```
std::vector<Foo*> fooVector; //contains some 100 elements
std::vector<Bar*> barVector; //contains some 10,000 elements
```

The idea is that there will always be far more Bar objects than Foo objects. However, each Foo object needs to be associated with a Bar object; so far, this is as simple as giving each Foo object a Bar pointer, and a getBar() function.

However, ***I need to be able to do the opposite as well***: given a Bar object, I need a way to immediately get its associated Foo, if there is any. The most straightforward way to accomplish this is to give each Bar a Foo pointer. This seems extremely redundant though, since I would be introducing 10,000 more ways for things to go wrong (not to mention only 100 of those would ever be valid, with the rest being nullptrs). The other way, which I have at the moment, is something like this:

```
Foo* getFooPtr(Bar* barObj){      
    for(auto& foo : fooVector){
        if(foo->getBar() == barObj)
            return foo;
    }
}
```

While it works, it is inefficient because it has to iterate through the entire fooVector every time. This function needs to be run very often, so this is unacceptable.

I've considered using something like an std::map, but the same iteration issues ultimately remain.

Comment: What about two maps? `std::map<Foo*, Bar*> foo_bar_map;` and `std::map<Bar*, Foo*> bar_foo_map;`?

Comment: @gomons, another approach but with the same problem: Redundancy and possible inconsistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector of 10,000 elements is not "10,000 more ways for things to go wrong". If you do the same to all the elements, it's just *one* more way for things to go wrong - the code which fills the pointer data.

I'd go with the double linking, in the absence of a better approach, which I could only design if I had a wider perspective of the problem. With that wider perspective, a better option is likely to exist, probably involving sets and maps - especially if you need to do intensive searches for one bar's foo and for one foo's bar.

Encapsulate your pointer settings in a function which guarantees that the pair is consistent, and you'll be safe.

In particular, you should try that option and see if it poses specific problems to you. StackOverflow will be here to address them.

You can fix mistakes, but you can't fix code which hasn't been written yet for fear of making mistakes.

Comment: By 10,000 ways for things to go wrong, I meant giving each Bar a Foo pointer. Of all the Bar objects, only 100 would have pointers that aren't null.

Comment: @Bluejay I understood that in the first place. My answer was written with that in mind. The size of your vector is not the direct number of ways that you have for things to go wrong. That is more related to the cyclomatic complexity of your code.

Answer (score 3):

> [...] so far, this is as simple as giving each Foo object a Bar pointer, and a getBar() function.

In this case, this:

```
Foo* getFooPtr(Bar* barObj){      
    for(auto& foo : fooVector){
        if(foo->getBar() == barObj)
            return foo;
    }
}
```

is madness.

If you give each `Foo` object a `Bar` pointer, why not give each `Bar` a `Foo` pointer?

```
class Foo
{
protected:
    Bar* _bar;

public:
    void setBar(Bar* bar);
    Bar* getBar() const;
};


class Bar
{
    friend class Foo; //allow Foo to set _foo pointer

protected:
    Foo* _foo;

public:
    Foo* getFoo() const;
};


void Foo::setBar(Bar* bar)
{
    this->_bar = bar;
    bar->_foo = this;
}

Bar* Foo::getBar() const
{
    return this->_bar;
}

Foo* Bar::getFoo() const
{
    return this->_foo;
}
```

The, every time you associate `Bar` object with `Foo` object, both will automatically save this association - you will be able to get `Bar` pointer from `Foo` and vice versa:

```
Foo* f = ...;
f->setBar(...);
```

Now:

```
Bar* b = f->getBar();
Foo* bf = b->getFoo();

assert( f == bf ); //This hould always be true
```

Comment: nice answer, but I was wondering about the opposite `Foo* f = b->getFoo();  Bar* fb = f->getBar();` the f may be null and the behavior of `f->getBar()` is undefined because not all Bar objects are associated with Foo objects

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care too much about space complexity and time complexity is your main concern, you may want to implement a hash table.

Look-up will be O(1) since you will not have buckets, and you will probably use less memory compared to storing 10.000 pointers (either they are null or not).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reduce the redundancy, create another vector

```
std::vector<std::pair<Bar *, Foo *> > barFooVector
```

which would serve as a reverse mapping for the 100 cases of bar to Foo.

To ensure that you do not tangle within the pointers, it is safer to use `std::shared_ptr` instead of naked pointers

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> fooVector; //contains some 100 elements
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Bar>> barVector; //contains some 10,000 elements
std::vector<std::pair<std::shared_ptr<Bar>, std::shared_ptr<Foo>> > barFooVector
std::vector<std::pair<std::shared_ptr<Foo>, std::shared_ptr<Bar>> > fooBarVector
```

Also it would be highly maintainable and scalable to create helper wrappers over these vectors